# Share on WhatsApp broken in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

I am facing an extremely weird situation. I have an app named ClubFactory installed on my iPhone. When I am pressing share to WhatsApp on my app it gives a message that your app wants to open "ClubFactory". To confirm whether my code has something wrong with it, I opened safari and tried the same URL and it also shows open "ClubFactory". Everything was working fine earlier. Have no clue where this crept in from !!
     I have tried this on 2 or 3 devices with club factory installed and it works the same. For devices having no ClubFactory installed it behaves normally.

```
let str = "your text"
let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=(str)")
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL! as URL) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL! as URL)
} else {
    showAlert(message: "Whatsapp is not installed on this device. Please install Whatsapp and try again.")
}
```

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: You can try use ""https://api.whatsapp..." instead "whatsapp..." Maybe help you.

Comment: @Kevinosaurio can't get ur url completely

Comment: @Kevinosaurio - the link is now broken

Answer (score 1):

The ClubFactory app has registered the `whatsapp` handler. When you use it instead of opening WhatsApp it opens ClubFactory. This is a really shady move by the ClubFactory app, you can report this to both WhatsApp and Apple.

To restore the right behavior try to remove ClubFactory, install WhatsApp, open WhatsApp, install ClubFactory.

Comment: Ya i did the same

Comment: But i believe that we need a solution

Comment: @Shebuka - What does "registered the whatsapp handler" exactly mean ?

I am facing a similar issue, but in my case sharing on YouTube is triggering my application instead of WhatsApp.

Trying to find out what exactly is the issue.

Comment: @Shailesh it's called custom URL scheme in Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app

Comment: @Shebuka - does that mean the URL scheme of my app and that of WhatsApp are same?
won't that be the case of most of the app who'd be wanting to open WhatsApp from their apps ?
Is there any appropriate way to handle this .. ?

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta - how did you manage to fix this ?